Count With K Different Characters
The problem is basically to count the number of substrings with exactly k distinct characters.There can be duplicate as long as there are k distinct characters.
I was trying sliding window method in which first I check if the element is distinct in the particular window by using a boolean function if the element is distinct then we increment the count and if the count is equal to k then increment answer by 1 and break the loop and restart the sliding window.

Did you read the tag description of dsa?

Please check out How to Ask a good question, and take the tour. There is currently no question in your post.

I googled count the number of substrings with exactly k distinct characters, and came up with multiple web pages of this exact problem, with code samples.  Did you do the proper research before posting your question (actually, no question was asked)?
